# How to get the fields and values of an updated row in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

**My code for update a row in sequelize - MySQL - Express is as below**

```
// Update an user
userController.update = function(req, res) {
  models.user.update(
  {
    user_name: req.body.name,
    user_address: req.body.address,
    user_email: req.body.email,
  }, {where: {user_id: req.params.id}, returning: true, plain: true})
  .then((user)=>{
    res.redirect("/users/show/"+user.user_id);
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
    res.render("../views/users/edit", {user: req.body});
  });   
};
```

---

But user.user_id is showing the value of undefined
How to get the fields and values of an updated row in sequelize

Answer (score 3):

`update` returns the number of rows affected as the first parameter. If you need the affected object, you can use `spread`

```
// Update an user
userController.update = function(req, res) {
  models.user.update(
  {
    user_name: req.body.name,
    user_address: req.body.address,
    user_email: req.body.email,
  }, {where: {user_id: req.params.id}, returning: true, plain: true})
  .spread((affectedCount, affectedRows) => {
    // use affectedRows here
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.render("../views/users/edit", {user: req.body});
  });   
};
```

If you want to use `.then`
Use like this `.then(function([ rowsUpdate, [usersUpdated] ]) {`

Answer (score 1):

As of official doc, this is supported only for postgres with  `options.returning true`

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update

Comment: Those landing here from Google - apparently returning: true works only for postgres and not mariadb as per documentation